# Textinput maxLength is not working for default keyboard Type

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

[image]

```
//Here is my common component for Textinput
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={props?.autofocus}
      numberOfLines={1}
      editable={true}
      keyboardType={props?.keyboardType}
      style={[styles.editText,{paddingLeft:props?.adjustPadding == true ?'7%':'3%'}]}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      defaultValue={props?.value}
      maxLength={props.maxLength}
      autoCapitalize={props?.autoCapitalize}
      onChangeText={text => props.onChangeText(props.placeholder, text)}
    />
  );
}

export default CustomTextInput;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  editText: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 6,
    borderColor: '#e4e4e6',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    paddingLeft: '3%',
    // marginTop: '3%',
    width:'100%',
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'black',
  },
});
```

Here is my code where I am importing TextInput from common class

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import CustomTextInput from '../Common/CustomTextInput';

function EditContact(props) {
  const [details, setDetails] = React.useState({
    phone: '',
    gstin: '',
  });

  const onChangeText = (type, value) => {
    try {
      switch (type) {
        case 'Phone':
          setDetails({
            ...details,
            phone: value,
          });

          break;

        case 'GSTIN':
          if(value.length == 15){
            setDetails({
              ...details,
              gstin: value,
            });
          }
          break;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('EditContactonChangeTextEroor', error);
    }
  };

  return (
        <View style={{margin: '2%'}}>
            <CustomTextInput
              placeholder={'Phone'}
              onChangeText={onChangeText}
              keyboardType={'numeric'}
              maxLength={15}/>
          <View style={{marginTop: '4%'}} />
            <CustomTextInput
              placeholder={'GSTIN'}
              onChangeText={onChangeText}
              maxLength={15}
              autoCapitalize={'characters'}
              keyboardType={'default'}
            />
        </View>
  );
}
export default EditContact;
```

I have two TextInput fields called phone and GSTIN which I am using to allow user for entering their values. I have set maxLength 15 and KeyboardType for both the fields. The maxLength is working for the textinput which has keyboardType numeric and for default keyboardType the maxLength property is not working and its allowing user to enter more than 15 characters.

The characters which exceeds maxLength is not visible in the textInput but its allowing to type more than 15 characters for only default keyboardType.

It's working perfectly for numeric KeyboardType. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is working fine for me. Check [this](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/keyboard-maxlength) snack out.

Comment: check with real device.its allowing to type more than 15 characters but those characters are not visible in textinput.but it is visible in keyboard

Comment: the problem is there in the snack too?

Comment: Check out [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/kartikeyvaish/video/upload/v1679995178/StackOverflow/IMG_5619_dvzcdm.mov) video. I tested it on a physical device.

Comment: @Kartikey please check above edited question

Comment: can you add a screen recording of the issue that you are facing? It isn't clear with the image you provided.

Comment: @Kartikey please see the keyboard its allowing to type more than 15 characters